# Quickbooks credit card reconciliation

Tags: accounting, quickbooks, reconciling

When I put a payment into Quickbooks through the enter bills section and then pay it, when I go to reconcile the account the payment does not show up. Why would this be and how can it be placed in the proper area to be reconciled?

Comment: Which version of Quickbooks? Are you sure you selected "Credit Card" and the correct credit card account for the payment in Pay Bill window?